# Auto scroll with click on pause and unpause again on click not working

Tags: javascript, scroll, onclick, onclicklistener

I want to know how to make the web page im working auto scroll and then stop on click or (hover over some text but that's too complex for me) and then restart the auto scroll when clicked again until it reaches the bottom of the page.  Forgive my ignorance I have very little knowledge of JS and I'm just starting to learn it.
here's what i've got so far...

```
let scrollerId;
let paused = true;
function startScroll(){

let id = setInterval(function(){ window.scrollBy(0,2); }, 10);
return id; }

function stopScroll() {
  clearInterval(scrollerId);
}

scrollerId = startScroll();

 document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  
     if(scroll == true){
       scrollerId = stopScroll();
        paused = true;
     } else {
       scrollerId = startScroll();
       paused = false;
     }
   }
                               
  );
```

I tried this but i'm obviously doing something wrong. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you explain me clearly what are you trying to achieve, what do you mean by auto-scroll? Do you mean to scroll to the point where user left before?

Answer (score 0):

1. The **if statement** should be checking if the variable **paused** is true or false, instead it is checking if scroll is true or false.
2. Set paused to false on the start of the code; assuming paused is set to false:

   ```
   document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

   if(paused == true){
     stopScroll();
     paused = true;
   } else {
   scrollerId = startScroll();
   paused = false;
     }
   }
   );
   ```

Comment: Ah thanks @SmallRock - but now i have this and the click doesn't work - just auto scrolls to bottom.  if set the let "paused = true" click works to stop but not to start.  
`let scrollerId;
let paused = false;
function startScroll(){

let id = setInterval(function(){ window.scrollBy(0,2); }, 10);
return id; }

function stopScroll() {
  clearInterval(scrollerId);
}

scrollerId = startScroll();
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

if(paused == true){
  stopScroll();
  paused = true;
} else {
scrollerId = startScroll();
paused = false;
  }
}
); `